# How to create a large Offline data repository android app?

Tags: android, offline

I am creating an Android app for my teachers. It will be a completely offline app containing videos and documents relating to mechanical engineering. It is a data repository app. What is the best way to store these data(around 2-3Gb or may be more) in the app?

Comment: Honestly, I would not make that kind of app ... if you still want one way is to store all assets in resources directory and play them on user request

Answer (score 0):

You can consider storing the files in cache that way those files wont be seen by user in the file manager and you can access them easily.
`File.createTempFile(filename, null, context.cacheDir)`
This is how you can store it and then you can store their names or path in Room database.
You can refer to the official documentation for that:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#internal

Comment: But in this case, I can't share just the apk to all the teachers. Everytime I install it in their device, I have to transfer these files seperately to their device!!